# Can m2e install an external jar file? Or do I need to install the maven command line tool?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I guess this is a best practices question. I'm asking as someone new to both Maven and m2e.
Stackoverflow suggested this question:
[How to tell M2Eclipse to install jar file as a maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209950/how-to-tell-m2eclipse-to-install-jar-file-as-a-maven-dependency)

which suggests it is possible to install from the GUI but seems convoluted, as you have to create a dummy run configuration. I.e. no one click add file and give it a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. M2e is just a way to run mvn from inside eclipse. It is not a practical or recommended practice to run mvn install:install-file as part of a build (and then depend on the results)( so it is still no good in m2e.

Comment: @Daniel If you are seriously moving to maven, I'll strongly recommend installing the command line. It's very simple in any OS

Comment: Well, "seriously" implies willingness. I'm rather ambivalent, but since it's been forced on me by Google's PlayN architecture, I don't really have a say in the matter. :-/

The wonders of plumbing! Thanx for your responses.

Comment: ...and no installer which configures paths... how I'm in need of some TLC :-(