# How to add the ojdbc jar manually into eclipse integrated maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

iam trying to run the command in command prompt  **mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgeneratePom=true** 
  but its thrown the error "mvn is not recognized internal or external command"
then i have searched in internet i found many resources like they separately download the maven and they set the path into environment variable, but i don't want like that, already my eclipse(kepler) have internally contain the maven and it is working properly. so please help me how to to add the ojdbc14 jar in maven local repository.

Comment: Follow the instructions on http://maven.apache.org/install.html to correctly install maven so you can run it on the commandline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell M2Eclipse to install jar file as a maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209950/how-to-tell-m2eclipse-to-install-jar-file-as-a-maven-dependency)